# Windows 7 REG ADD and %DATE%

Tags: batch-file, registry

I need to write a Date stamp into the registry from a .BAT script.  I've tried the following examples but no luck so far...

```
reg add hklm\software\test /v datestamp /d %%DATE%% /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /f
```

```
reg add hklm\software\test /v datestamp /d %DATE% /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /f
```

```
reg add hklm\software\test /v datestamp /d ^%DATE^% /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /f
```

Can someone point me to how this can be done properly?  Thanks!

Comment: Is there any specific format you need the "date stamp" to be in, or do you have examples? What about regional settings: is it just for your current regional settings/on your current machine or do you need something more general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the date format is already OK, just add quotes:

```
reg add hklm\software\test /v datestamp /d "%DATE%" /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /f
```