# Writing %~DP0 to Registry using REG ADD

Tags: windows, batch-file, registry

I've resolved the question I had about inserting %DATE% into a REG_SZ registry value ([see link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5759723/windows-7-reg-add-and-date)), but now I'm running into a slightly different problem trying to insert %~DP0 (long source path) into a registry value using REG ADD within a .BAT script.  It won't do it, and I'm sure it's because I'm doing something wrong.

```
reg add "hklm\software\acme" /v "TestValue" /d "%~dp0" /t REG_SZ /f
```

I've also tried setting the value to a variable first, but that doesn't work either.  What happens is that it inserts the expanded path without the preceeding double-quote, but with a trailing double-quote, and then bombs with an error about REG /? syntax, etc.

```
SET VX=%~DP0
reg add "hklm\software\acme" /v "TestValue" /d "%VX%" /t REG_SZ /f
```

Anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The path %~dp0 ends in the directory separator character '\' (e.g. 'c:\temp\') which is being interpreted as an escape for the following double-quote character and so the parser is not seeing the closing double-quote. What you need to do is escape the trailing \ character with another one:

```
reg add "hklm\software\acme" /v "TestValue" /d "%~dp0\" /t REG_SZ /f
```

Comment: Alternative way: using `"%~dp0."`